# How to use ILogger in DomainObjects?

Tags: azure, logging, azure-functions

I have a Azure Function App with FunctionRuntime v3 and dependency injection.

Normally I inject the logger using

```cs
public TestRepositoryy(ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
     _tenantBasedDocumentClient = tenantBasedDocumentClient;
     _log = loggerFactory.CreateLogger(GetType().Namespace);
}
```

How can I inject ILogger into something like domain objects, where the object is not created via Startup-Configuration

Answer (score 0):

Though it's recommended to use dependency injection where you could simply declare `ILogger<TestRepository>` in constructor and Function runtime will automatically resolve the logger.

```
public TestRepositoryy(ILogger<TestRepository> logger)
{
     _log = logger;
}
```

But since you mentioned you are not creating the domain object by DI, you can pass the `ILogger` instance from the caller Function when you create the object.

```
public TestRepository(ILogger logger)
{
     _log = logger;
}

// below is the Function entry point where ILogger is automatically injected.
public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run(HttpRequestMessage req, ILogger logger)
{
    var myRepository = TestRepository(logger);
    // blah blah
}
```

Read more about ILogger in Function [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/azure-functions/functions-monitoring?#write-logs-in-c-functions)